# Atmel ASM not working when enabling call

Tags: assembly, arduino, atmel, atmega

I am a student applied computer science, at the end of the year we had an assignment to create the hardware for an dice and program it in assembly. The hardware consist of 2 buttons and 7 leds, the leds are arranged in the following figure (where an + is an LED and an dot is nothing(spacing))

```
+...+
+.+.+
+...+
```

One of the buttons is the throw button, it is constantly checked in the loop and the program acts accordingly. The other button is for the history mode, a little extra for the dice. I have implemented the complete assembly code for the dice with history mode but it is not working (nothing happens), but when I comment out my calls for the setupHistory and clearHistory it is working like normal (but without the history mode).

The code will run on an Arduino Uno R3 with an Atmega328P chip.

These are my defines:

```
.DEF TMP = R16
.DEF RND = R17
.DEF PRM = R18
.DEF RTN = R19
.DEF BUTTON_STATE = R20         ; bit 0: cur throw button state
.DEF PREV_BUTTON_STATE  = R21   ; bit 0: prev throw button state
.DEF ANIMATION_STATE = R22      
.DEF COUNTER = R23
```

The data segment for the history:

.DSEG

```
.ORG 0x0100
h1: .BYTE 1 ; History 1
h2: .BYTE 1 ; History 2
h3: .BYTE 1 ; History 3
h4: .BYTE 1 ; History 4
h5: .BYTE 1 ; History 5
```

Interrupt vector table:

```
.CSEG
.ORG 0x0000                 ; Reset interrupt
    RJMP main
.ORG INT0addr                   ; Int0 interrupt
    RJMP INT0_interrupt
.ORG OVF1addr                   ; Timer/Counter1 Compare Match A
    RJMP timer1_overflow        
.ORG OVF0addr                   ; Timer/Counter0 Overflow
    RJMP timer0_overflow
```

The main 'method' which initializes everything:

```
.ORG 0x0033
main:
CLI                     ; Disable interrupts

CALL initializeStack    ; Initialize the stack
CALL loadRegisters      ; Load default register values
CALL setupPorts         ; Setting up ports

                        ; Clear interrupts
CALL setupTimer0        ; Setting up Timer 0
CALL setupTimer1        ; Setting up Timer 1

;CALL setupHistory      ; History button
;CALL clearHistory      ; Clear history

SEI                     ; Enable interrupts

RJMP loop               ; Jump to loop
```

And this is where the problem occurs, when uncommenting the calls for setupHistory and clearHistory the dice isn't working anymore (when commented it is working okay).

This is the code where it jumps to:

```
setupHistory:
LDI TMP, 0b00000011 ; 0b00000011
STS EICRA, TMP  ; Rising edge

LDI TMP, (1 << INT0)
OUT EIMSK, TMP

RET

INT0_interrupt:
IN PRM, PORTB

// Display h1
LDS TMP, h1
OUT PORTB, TMP
RCALL DELAY_HALF_SECOND

// Display h2
LDS TMP, h2
OUT PORTB, TMP
RCALL DELAY_HALF_SECOND

// Display h3
LDS TMP, h3
OUT PORTB, TMP
RCALL DELAY_HALF_SECOND

// Display h4
LDS TMP, h4
OUT PORTB, TMP
RCALL DELAY_HALF_SECOND

// Display h5
LDS TMP, h5
OUT PORTB, TMP
RCALL DELAY_HALF_SECOND

// Restore state
OUT PORTB, PRM

RETI

; PRM -> New number to store
; RTN -> Number that is removed
StoreToSram:
CLI

LDS TMP, h1
STS h1, PRM

LDS PRM, h2
STS h2, TMP

LDS TMP, h3
STS h3, PRM

LDS PRM, h4
STS h4, TMP

LDS RTN, h5
STS h5, PRM

SEI

RET

// TODO
clearHistory:
LDI TMP, 1  ; Keep vcc

STS h1, TMP
STS h2, TMP
STS h3, TMP
STS h4, TMP
STS h5, TMP

RET
```

If there is more information needed ask for it and you will get it!

Comment: Why the need for assembler? The same can be achieved using plain C and it's much more readable. Anyway, make sure your level interrupt pin is set to input, not output. You might trigger it yourself. While the datasheet indicates the interrupt state is cleared automatically, do it explicitly by writing a '1' to the status bit. Does your switch include a pull down? If not, the pin might float and you get *stuck* in the INT0 interrupt. Include a PD resistor **or** invert logic and use the MCU's internal PU resistor. It's a Bad Idea™ to wait in your ISR. Set a flag and do your logic in main loop!

Comment: The need for an assembler is because this is an assignment that has to be written in assembly, so C is not valid (read first line of post). The pins are set up correctly for input and output, the other button works so I do not think this is the problem. And yes I might trigger it myself, thats the idea of an button... For the automatic interrupt state clearing: Why would it work on one button, but fail on the other? Yes, a pull down is used in the circuit, and I agree waiting in an interrupt being an bad idea, but is that the problem for not even working? (button never pressed when running)

Comment: "And yes I might trigger it myself, thats the idea of an button..." => I meant you might trigger it accidentally in unrelated code performing changes on the same port. Running long code in the ISR blocks all other interrupts (your timer interrupts, for example). You might get an initial INT0 interrupt, depending on the status register which is not reset. Determine which of the two function calls actually breaks your program (I bet setupHistory). "Why would it work on one button, but fail on the other" You said you poll the other button. If you use INT1, then you left out some important code.

Comment: Okay, I understand the concept of an interrupt interrupting everything else, but that is the whole idea of the history mode: Stop what you are doing and display the history of everything that  has happened. I want to add that timer0 is used as an "random" so that should not give an problem and timer1 is used for animation on rolling the dice, these two must been interrupted when showing history. Triggering it accidentally by code is not possible because I do not change the portd register of he arduino (int0 is pin 2 on the arduino), it should even be completly seperated

Comment: You're going about interrupts in a very naive fashion. You should refactor your code to do all the processing in the main loop. Your problem is likely an interaction with code you haven't shown yet...